# What happened to the new custom close reason?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Recently, we added a [New custom close reason](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/new-custom-close-reason). However, I cannot see this reason anymore:

[image]

Was it removed?

Comment: It should be available now. Let me know if it is not.

Comment: It's available now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was edited in response to [your suggestion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1180/929) and is awaiting approval from another moderator before it can be reactivated. I don't think it shows up in any of the review queues so I will ping the other moderators.

Comment: Oh OK, I didn't know the reason was removed while being edited. Thanks for implementing the suggestion!

Comment: @CharlesMorisset It seems strange to me also. I may have clicked something I wasn't supposed to in the process, but I don't think so.